# How to make two curl calls in same script

Tags: php, api, curl

I am making API call to third party via curl php.
the code is working but since I am making two POST and GET one after another I have to refresh the page to get response for GET call

I tried using ajax and it is throwing me CORS errors

```
function callAPI($method, $url, $data){ 
    global $company_api_key;
    switch ($method){
    case "POST":
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                        'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode("$company_api_key") ,
                        'Content-Type: application/json',
                        ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        // EXECUTE:
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
        curl_close($curl);
        return $result;
        break;
    case "GET": 
        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                        'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode("$company_api_key") ,
                        'Content-Type: application/json',
                        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        // EXECUTE:
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
        break;
    default:
        echo "something went wrong with API call";
    }
}
$make_call = callAPI('POST', 'post-url', json_encode($data_array));
```

I get an ID after this call and then I use that id in GET call

```
 $get_data = callAPI('GET', 'get-url'.$id, false);
```

now I am calling them one after another so I tried using AJAX for GET call but I am getting CORS error.

Comment: CORS shouldn't affect calling an API from PHP, only from the browser.

Comment: Can I achieve this via curl and without refreshing browser?

Comment: I can't see why not. The browser doesn't care what the PHP script is doing.

Comment: Then why does it work when I refresh and not the first time . POST happens first time and to get reply from GET I have to refresh

Comment: The function you posted doesn't display anything, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem you're describing.

Comment: What does the script do with the variables `$make_call` and `$get_data`?